# Why am I getting a question ban?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, reopen-request, post-ban

I have only asked 2 or 3 questions and got a ban without that warning. Is my status on other SE sites causing me to have a premature question ban here?

Comment: It might be rate limiting, not a full question ban. What message do you get?

Comment: @BenN No longer accepting questions from this account.

Comment: The answer [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309098/will-asking-a-really-good-question-get-you-more-chances-to-ask-more-questions) is some really good advice

Answer (score 10):

You have asked a total of 10 questions on Super User, 8 of which have been closed and/or deleted.

Your deleted questions, from newest to oldest:

- [Can you see me? [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/1294774/can-you-see-me)
- [Does SE have a webmaster? [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/1282257/does-se-have-a-webmaster)
- [What is the best way to change my IP? [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/1280988/what-is-the-best-way-to-change-my-ip)
- [Long distance with VR? [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/1280449/long-distance-with-vr)
- [Laptop Supercomputer via bluetooth/Wifi?](https://superuser.com/questions/1048463/laptop-supercomputer-via-bluetooth-wifi)
- [PlayStation Super Computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1026034/playstation-super-computer)
- [Add a video button like a picture button. Not a screen shot, but clip shot [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/1023681/add-a-video-button-like-a-picture-button-not-a-screen-shot-but-clip-shot)
- [How do I GIF a video clip easily? [duplicate]](https://superuser.com/questions/1023663/how-do-i-gif-a-video-clip-easily)

I don't really see any way to salvage any of the latest ones to make them worth undeleting as they are almost completely off-topic here.

The only thing you can do is to read [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://superuser.com/help/question-bans) and follow the advice there.  You *might* be able to improve your latest question in order to get people to upvote it, which could help.

Comment: Ninja'd ..... :)

Comment: @DavidPostill  Can they be undeleted so I can improve on them? If they count why delete?

Comment: @Muze They are **bad** questions that are off-topic. They cannot be undeleted without making them entirely different questions. From the help page I linked: `At Stack Exchange, asking questions is a privilege, not a right.`

Answer (score 7):

#### I have only asked 2 or 3 questions

You have asked 10 questions.

---

#### Is my status on other SE sites causing me to have a premature question ban here?

No. Your status on other SE sites makes no difference to your status on SuperUser.

- On SuperUser you have asked 10 questions.
- Those 10 questions have a total of 18 downvotes. Only 1 question has an upvote.
- 8 of those downvoted questions have been closed and deleted.

Please read [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://superuser.com/help/question-bans)

Answer (score 2):

Reading your deleted questions you have the creativity of Wile E Coyote, but you don't appear to have done ANY of the homework necessary to begin to turn those crazy and creative ideas into good questions.

First, I suggest you read the Help section to learn the few rules that govern this place and the many suggestions for how to write good questions that will attract good feedback and good answers.

Second, read the questions that are NOT deleted from the site (it's easy right now: all you should be able to see are the questions that aren't deleted). Note what many of them do, especially the ones that have attracted upvotes: The writer has a problem with their basically normal computer, does some research and tries fixing things themselves a bit, but have come upon some point or issue they cannot figure out themselves. They communicate all this or are guided through doing so, and then answers usually come.

Now look at your question history: You hear about some cool idea that tickles your fancy, usually involving parallel computing or slaving gaming systems into advanced parallel processing systems. You don't realize that these systems have been engineered by people with depths of study and experience and expertise in their fields, and instead your questions communicate that you think this is a relatively simple sort of setup others have done frequently (when it isn't) and that there are plenty of us going around with PlayStation super-computers in our bedrooms and willing to share that knowledge with you in spite of your showing no real effort to gain that knowledge yourself.

You see a cool toy and you appear to think SuperUser is the place to get that cool toy.

That's a fundamental misunderstanding of what SuperUser is, and questions asked in that misunderstanding stand a high likelihood, as you have experienced, of being downvoted and closed, and their askers finding themselves with bans.

Comment: I didn't hear of some idea they are all mine